# Get last requirement number run by SSS including not run

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in a test output database where we connect requirements towards testcases that has been executed. The tables look like the following:

```
mysql> select * from SSS_Req;
+-----+------+
| ID  | Req  |
+-----+------+
|   2 | 1122 |
|   3 | 1208 |
|   4 | 2525 |
+-----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> select * from log_item;
+----+------+---------+-------------------------+
| ID | Req  | Status  | DateTime                |
+----+------+---------+-------------------------+
| 32 | 2525 | SUCCESS | 2012-10-09 18:24:54.375 |
| 33 | 1122 | FAIL    | 2012-10-09 18:24:54.390 |
| 65 | 2525 | SUCCESS | 2012-10-09 18:44:40.625 |
+----+------+---------+-------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to get a table with all requirements sorted in time since last executed (descending), including requirements that isn't even executed (preferbly first in list). This is to help us get a list of requirements that has A. not been tested, B. not been tested in a long while.

So given the information above I would like to get an output similar to this:

```
+------+-------------------------+
| SSS  | DateTime                |
+------+-------------------------+
| 1208 | NULL                    |
| 1122 | 2012-10-09 18:24:54.390 |
| 2525 | 2012-10-09 18:44:40.625 |
+------+-------------------------+
```

Best Regards
Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.Req SSS,
        MAX(b.datetime) DateTime
FROM    SSS_req a
        LEFT JOIN Log_Item b
            ON a.req = b.req
GROUP   BY a.Req
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10637/3)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly once I added an ORDER BY DateTime in the end.

Comment: @Andreas that;s what on the fiddle `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You need a `left outer join` to get all the reqs.  And then a `group by` to get the last log time:

```
select r.req as SSS, MAX(datetime)
from sss_req r left outer join
     log_item li
     on r.req = li.req
group by r.req
```